# How to send message to specific socket with Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have some socket with verification:

```
defmodule Test.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  ## Channels
  channel "user:*", Test.RoomChannel

  def connect(_params, socket) do
    case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "user",  _params["token"]) do
          {:ok, uid} ->
            {:ok, assign(socket, :user_id, uid)}
          {:error, _} ->
            :error
     end
  end

 def id(_socket), do: "user:#{_socket.assigns.user_id}"
end
```

And after connect socket named like `user:#id`

From the documentation I can send disconnect event 
`Test.Endpoint.broadcast("users_socket:" <> user.id, "disconnect", %{})`

**Question:** How to send custom event to socket by `user:#id`, it should be like a push notification to specific socket.

I tried `Test.Endpoint.broadcast "user:1", "new:msg", %{user: "SYSTEM", body: "iex"}` but it's doesn't work, because i can't listen "new:msg" on socket.

Comment: It's works when I join the specific room `var chan = socket.channel("user:1", {})` but it's require additional verification in `join`

Comment: You do it on a channel like you described. You don't need to verify in join/3 if you've already verified and assigned a current user on the socket in connect. Just check socket.assigns.user_id against whatever room the user is trying to join. Then you broadcast to that room `Endpoint.broadcast "rooms:1", "new_msg", %{user: "SYSTEM", body: "iex"}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So we works only on 'room' bases. And my sources will be like: `def join("user:"<> _uid, message, socket) do if _uid == socket.assigns.user_id do
         {:ok, socket}
      else
         {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
      end
    end`

Comment: Hey @ChrisMcCord would you please post your response as an answer so others who may see this question in the future can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying Chris McCord's answer down from the comment:

You do it on a channel like you described. You don't need to verify in `join/3` if you've already verified and assigned a current user on the socket in connect. Just check `socket.assigns.user_id` against whatever room the user is trying to join. Then you broadcast to that room `Endpoint.broadcast "rooms:1", "new_msg", %{user: "SYSTEM", body: "iex"}`

(Marking answer as community wiki since I don't want the rep points if anyone decides to upvote this. It's not my answer :) )

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the answer. So we works only on 'room' bases. And my
>   sources will be like: def join("user:"<> _uid, message, socket) do if
>   _uid == socket.assigns.user_id do {:ok, socket} else {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}} end end

you don't need to verify the userId again since you already have defined the logic in UserSocket#connect if the user is not authenticated he gets a message that he is not authorize, what you can do is use the userId to check if the user has permission to view a specific channel for instance

```
def join("rooms:some_private_room", message, socket) do 
  if socket.assigns.user_id do 
    {:ok, socket}
  else 
    # kick him out he is not allowed here
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}} 
  end 
end
```